# How to get row with default value when data not found in table

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I have a table which holds some data with date field.

Ex:

```
|SCHEDULED_DATE |
---------------
|06-MAY-2016    |
|08-MAY-2016    |
|10-JUL-2016    |
```

Now I need to get the count of days for each month.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM SCHEDULE
WHERE SEQ = '429' 
AND TO_CHAR((SCHEDULED_DATE),'MON-YYYY')='MAY-2016')=0
THEN 0
ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM SCHEDULE
WHERE SEQ = '429' 
AND TO_CHAR((SCHEDULED_DATE),'MON-YYYY')='MAY-2016')
END 
AS NO_OF_DAYS, NVL(TO_CHAR((SCHEDULED_DATE),'MON'),'MAY') AS MONTH
FROM SCHEDULE
WHERE SEQ = '429';
```

In the `NVL` I will update the alternate value for each month before executing

When I run this query for the month of `MAY` I get the value 2 and the output is like this .

```
|NO_OF_DAYS |MONTH|
------------ -----
|2          |MAY  |
```

But for the month of `JUN` i need to show it as 0, but the output is like this

```
|NO_OF_DAYS |MONTH|
------------ -----
|           |     |
```

My desired output is like this

```
|NO_OF_DAYS |MONTH|
------------ -----
|0          |JUN  |
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Note: I have updated my question as it was not clear. Sorry i was not able ask properly the first time.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Your query would return exactly one row.  Yet you are showing  a result set with three rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No i gave an example this query gets the `seq` and `month` value dynamically from my program

Comment: . . I repeat:  The query in your question will return *exactly* one row.  The count will be zero if no rows match.  Your overall question does not make sense.  Perhaps you should ask another question and show more complete code.

Comment: It seems the query you wrote will return exactly those numbers: 2 for MAY, 0 for JUNE, 1 for JULY. Are you saying there is something wrong with that output? If so, what?

Comment: @mathguy i have updated my query kindly have a look

Comment: I don't get it. The query you posted originally did exactly what you wanted. Why did you change it to one that doesn't?

Comment: @mathguy this is what i was trying to find. thought if got solution for that i would do this myself but as you pointed out it was working properly when executed separately and the problem was when executing like this. Sorry my bad

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you may need something like this:

```
SQL> select count(1), parameter
  2      from (select '07-2016' parameter from dual)
  3           inner join schedule on parameter = to_char(SCHEDULED_DATE, 'mm-yyyy')
  4      where seq = '429';

  COUNT(1) PARAMET
---------- -------
         1 07-2016
```

Comment: Can u please explain on what `parameter` and `dual` refer to

Comment: @TonyRoczz parameter is just an alias I gave to the date, dual is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries009.htm#SQLRF20036)

Answer (score 0):

Your query will give result which you expect.

If you want to get results in one query please do:

```
select to_char(SCHEDULED_DATE, 'mon-yyyy'), count(*) FROM SCHEDULE
--optionally to get only some months
where to_char(SCHEDULED_DATE, 'mon-yyyy') in (/*fill values from your array here*/) 
and seq = '439'
group by to_char(SCHEDULED_DATE, 'mon-yyyy');
```

If you also want to do that for different seq you can do:

```
select to_char(SCHEDULED_DATE, 'mon-yyyy'), seq, count(*) FROM SCHEDULE
    --optionally to get only some months
    where to_char(SCHEDULED_DATE, 'mon-yyyy') in (/*fill values from your array here*/) 
    and seq in (/*fill values from array of seqs*/)
    group by to_char(SCHEDULED_DATE, 'mon-yyyy'), seq;
```

this will return counts per seq for each month which you can then process on Java side.